# How to make header logo clickable?

Tags: html, css, blogger

Please give me instructions how to fix some Blogger codes. I just made an image logo and put it beside my blog title (behind title and description/using awesome template). I got successful making the blog title clickable, but no success in finding how to make the image logo clickable. I also tried putting my URL in

```
<div id='header-inner'>
<a expr:href='data:blog.homepageUrl' style='display: block'>
```

still not changing.
I tried changing it in the Chrome console using this code it worked, but I don't know how to fix it in the source html.

```
<a href="#">
<div id="header-inner
</a>
```

I inspect the page and tried some CSS codes but only made me more confused. Please give me some instructions how to fix...Big big thanks to all.

```
<div id='header-inner'>
    <a expr:href='data:blog.homepageUrl' style='display: block'>
    <img expr:alt='data:title' expr:height='data:height' 
     expr:id='data:widget.instanceId + &quot;_headerimg&quot;' 
     expr:src='data:sourceUrl' expr:width='data:width' style='display: 
     block'/>
    </a>
    <b:if cond='data:imagePlacement == &quot;BEFORE_DESCRIPTION&quot;'>
        <b:include name='description'/>
    </b:if>
</div>
</b:if>
<b:else/>
<div id='header-inner'>
<div class='titlewrapper'>
<h1 class='title'>

element.style {
background-image: url(//3.bp.blogspot.com/- 
yjBU04mgpNw/W0l9tFJDjEI/AAAAAAAADRw/- 
uOagCGc3cIhBSJsH3Zl4RetnKK_iuhUQCK4BGAYYCw/s1600/101bloggertips-logo.png);
background-position: left;
width: 120px;
min-height: 37px;
_height: 37px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: what's your blog url ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a div element to specifically target a smaller zone around your image and not the whole header.

Try replacing :

```
<a href="#">
<div id="header-inner
</a>
```

With :

```
<div class="header-inner>
<div class="logo-container">
<a href ="#">
<img src="Your image url" class ="logo_header" alt="My Logo">
</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Then you can add some css using your logo_container and logo_header classes as follow :

```
.logo_container {
    width:200px;
    height:auto;
    display: block;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-bottom:60px;
}

.logo_header {
    width:200px;
    height:auto;
}
```

Hope it helps !